# Alternative to sticky position?

Tags: javascript, html, css

CSS sticky position is not supported in IE browser, and can't use fixed as an alternative.

Is there any way in which I can apply sticky behaviour to an element without using sticky position?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your post is more likely to get high-quality answers if you show examples and include code snippets that explain your previous attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's not supported by the browser, you can either:

- Use a polyfill library, such as https://github.com/wilddeer/stickyfill
- Implement the sticky functionality yourself, with JS.